# Trouble using string.replace() Javascript with Unicode Symbols

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a javascript function to move a pointing arrow from one html element to another. "&#9664" displays an arrow in HTML.

The trouble is that while I can add an arrow to innerHTML I can't seem to remove the arrow from the current selection.

Here is the relevent portion of my code:

```
var current;
function changeArrowFunction(line) {
if (typeof current != 'undefined')
    current.innerHTML = current.innerHTML.replace(" &#9664","");
line.innerHTML = line.innerHTML + " &#9664";
current = line;
}
```

I tried changing around the typeof condition or removing it completely with no sign of improvement, so it seems the problem is with replace().

Comment: Is that space supposed to be there `" &#9664"`? Also it doesn't seem like you are correct defining your function, you need the `function` keyword before hand. Finally it looks like you are just placing it back in anyways.

Comment: function thing was a typo (fixed), the space is supposed to be there, or else I would add a space every time the arrow moved. I want there to be no trace of the arrow.

Comment: i would wrap a tag around it, like `<i>&#9664</i>` so you can remove() the _i_, which is a lot less janky than replacing innerHTML...

Comment: The problem with that is I end up with a bunch of <i> tags all over, and since this is looping through hundreds of times touching each line multiple times after a while I think it would break somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is inner html does not preserve the html codes so.

If you log/alert the value of `innerHTML` you could see that the character `◀` is visible there not the string `&#9664`, so the replace function won't be able to find the character sequence to replace it.

```js
var current;

function changeArrayFunction(line) {
  if (typeof current != 'undefined') {
    current.innerHTML = current.innerHTML.replace(" ◀", "");
  }
  line.innerHTML = line.innerHTML + " &#9664";
  current = line;
}

var c = 0;

function test() {
  changeArrayFunction(document.getElementById('d-' + (++c)))
}
```

```html
<div id="d-1">adf</div>
<div id="d-2">adf</div>
<div id="d-3">adf</div>
<div id="d-4">adf</div>
<button onclick="test();">Test</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please clarify what the problem is and how you're solving it?

Comment: Please identify what you changed, it looks the same as my code besides the brackets around the if statement, which I added and doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: @e.sterling `current.innerHTML.replace(" ◀", "");` ?